# ABS as constraint in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to have absolute value as a constraint in sql 2008. Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[myTable] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
CONSTRAINT [IX_Blah] UNIQUE  NONCLUSTERED 
(
    ABS([ID_1]),
    [ID_2]
)  ON [PRIMARY]
```

In my table ID_1 can be negative. So I need make sure I don't have records with

```
ID_1   ID_2
  1     1
 -1     1
```

They should be considered the same and not be allowed.

Thank you.

Comment: This is one of those times I would say try it and find out.

Comment: I tried, I can't do it exactly as posted, that's why I said "something like". Maybe there is a work around?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you've tried it and got an error.

No, unique constraints cannot include formulas.  You *can* however, have a unique constraint on a *computed* column:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
ADD  ID_3 AS ABS(ID_1) 

ALTER TABLE [myTable]ADD 
CONSTRAINT [IX_Blah] UNIQUE  NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_3],
    [ID_2]
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like a good idea. However I have restrictions. I can't add fields to this table. Anything else I can do?

Comment: Not as a unique constraint that I know of.  You'll have to enforce it through triggers or the application that does the inserts.